# Is it possible to start an Azure Pipeline from one specific job on

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

So I have quite a long pipeline in Azure and I am adding a new job to the end.
Is it somehow possible to start the pipeline right before that job using artifacts from a previous build?
I just need to figure out some paths and don't want to wait for the entire pipeline to build, just to realize a have wrong path in there.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Download artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to grab artifacts from a previous build. you'd need to comment\condition all the previous steps though, else they will run.